# Flow ---> Visual Workflow tag synonym outdated

Tags: feature-request

'Flow' tag is currently set as a synonym for 'visual-workflow' tag meaning that questions tagged 'flow' are auto-updated to 'visual-workflow'.

Since 'visual-workflow' is a retired feature I don't think that these two terms should still be regarded as synonyms.